# Ruby-opencv: What is the correspondent construct to C++ " addWeighted" in Ruby-opencv

Tags: ruby, opencv

C++ OpenCV has:

```
void addWeighted(InputArray src1, double alpha, InputArray src2, double beta, double gamma, OutputArray dst, int dtype=-1)
```

Python OpenCV has:

```
cv2.addWeighted(src1, alpha, src2, beta, gamma[, dst[, dtype]]) → dst
```

I am using Ruby-opencv, but I don't find this kind of method.

Somebody can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks promising: https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv/blob/master/examples/alpha_blend.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is here:

```
OpenCV::CvMat.add_weighted( img1, alpha, img2, beta, gamma )
```

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=addweighted#cv2.addWeighted

It seems opencv does not support direct ruby now.

Comment: I have this installed on my machine: https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-opencv and it seems to work ok

Comment: I also have installed Ruby-opencv, it works fine. But it seems not as complete as python-opencv. It seems there is no addWighted in Ruby-opencv, how to implement it?